# RecyclerView can not display the data retrieved from the server

Tags: java, android

How can I display the data using `RecyclerView`? Whenever data is retrieved from the server successfully, always not displayed on the screen (empty screen).

**MainActivity**

```
package com.transvision.bertho.transvisiondashboardapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import page.DefaultFragment;
import page.HomeFragment;
import page.ProfileFragment;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_test);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        Fragment fragment = null;
        fragment = new DefaultFragment();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.root, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        Fragment fragment = null;
        String title = getString(R.string.app_name);

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            title = "Home";
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
            fragment = new ProfileFragment();
            title = "Profile";
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.root, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }


    public void showToast(String output){
        Toast.makeText(this.getBaseContext(), output, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

**HomeFragment**

```
package page;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.transvision.bertho.transvisiondashboardapp.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import adapter.ChannelAdapter;
import butterknife.Bind;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import model.Channel;
import model.ChannelResponse;
import rest.ApiClient;
import rest.ApiInterface;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;


public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener{

    @Bind(R.id.movies_recycler_view) RecyclerView recyclerView;
    @Bind(R.id.swipe_layout) SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;

    private static final String TAG = HomeFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    private ChannelAdapter adapter;
    List<Channel> listChannel;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, rootView);

        listChannel = new ArrayList<>();

        setUpSwipeLayout();
        setUpAdapter();
        setUpRecyclerview();

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                load();
            }
        }, 500);

        return rootView;
    }

    protected void setUpSwipeLayout()
    {
        swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.colorPrimary, R.color.colorAccent);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
    }

    private void setUpAdapter(){
        if(adapter == null){
            adapter = new ChannelAdapter(listChannel, R.layout.list_channel, getActivity());
        }
    }

    private void setUpRecyclerview(){
        recyclerView.clearOnScrollListeners();
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    }

    private void load(){
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
        ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getChannel().create(ApiInterface.class);
        Call<ChannelResponse> call = apiService.getItems();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<ChannelResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ChannelResponse> call, Response<ChannelResponse> response) {
//                try {
//
//                }catch (Exception e){
//                    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
//                }

                listChannel = response.body().getItems();
                adapter = new ChannelAdapter(listChannel, R.layout.list_channel, getActivity());
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                Log.e(TAG, "CONNECTION SUCCESS");
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ChannelResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e(TAG, t.toString());
                showToast("CONNECTION ERROR");
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }

    public void showToast(String output){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), output, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        load();
    }
}
```

**ChannelAdapter**

```
package adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.transvision.bertho.transvisiondashboardapp.R;

import java.util.List;

import model.Channel;


public class ChannelAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ChannelAdapter.ChannelViewHolder> {

    private List<Channel> channels;
    private int rowLayout;
    private Context context;

    public ChannelAdapter(List<Channel> channels, int rowLayout, Context context) {
        this.channels = channels;
        this.rowLayout = rowLayout;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public static class ChannelViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        LinearLayout moviesLayout;

        TextView name;
        TextView description;
        TextView definition;

        public ChannelViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            moviesLayout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.movies_layout);
            name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
            definition = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.subtitle);
            description = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.description);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ChannelViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                            int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(rowLayout, parent, false);
        return new ChannelViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ChannelViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.name.setText(channels.get(position).getName());
        holder.definition.setText(channels.get(position).getDefinition());
        holder.description.setText(channels.get(position).getDescription());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return channels.size();
    }


}
```

When I run, i get a **log**

```
06-27 23:15:32.524 2537-2537/com.transvision.bertho.transvisiondashboardapp W/PathParser: Points are too far apart 4.000000596046461
06-27 23:15:33.532 2537-2537/com.transvision.bertho.transvisiondashboardapp W/PathParser: Points are too far apart 4.000000596046461
06-27 23:15:33.673 2537-2543/com.transvision.bertho.transvisiondashboardapp W/art: Suspending all threads took: 56.004ms
06-27 23:15:33.703 2537-2537/com.transvision.bertho.transvisiondashboardapp E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
06-27 23:15:34.639 2537-2543/com.transvision.bertho.transvisiondashboardapp W/art: Suspending all threads took: 16.331ms
06-27 23:15:35.225 2537-2543/com.transvision.bertho.transvisiondashboardapp W/art: Suspending all threads took: 113.297ms
06-27 23:15:35.234 2537-2537/com.transvision.bertho.transvisiondashboardapp I/Choreographer: Skipped 60 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-27 23:15:35.696 2537-2537/com.transvision.bertho.transvisiondashboardapp E/HomeFragment: CONNECTION SUCCESS
06-27 23:16:00.184 2537-2543/com.transvision.bertho.transvisiondashboardapp W/art: Suspending all threads took: 6.098ms
```

After I debug, i get 
[image]

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**app_bar_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.transvision.bertho.transvisiondashboardapp.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**fragment_home.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/movies_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**list_channel.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/movies_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="72dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
            android:textSize="16sp" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subtitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorGreyLight" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorGreyLight" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/rating_image"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/star"
            android:tint="@color/colorAccent" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rating"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:text="5.0" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Maybe there was a mistake in my code, please help for this case

Comment: Can you paste fragment's and adapter's xml layouts as well?

Comment: Hi @x0r check my update above

Comment: that looks ok. Did you try debugging your adapter? say whether the `onBindViewHolder` method is called..how many times it is called, e.t.c. This would help you to understand what could be a possible reason of the problem

Comment: is `recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);` executed in the UI thread?

Comment: Inside `onResponse` retrofit @Lino like my code above

Comment: Hi @x0r maybe you can see this https://s32.postimg.org/vstpz3zd1/debug.png

I do not really understand in reading

Comment: what about adapter's item xml layout?

Comment: Check my update @x0r . `list_channel.xml`

Comment: do one thing, on load method in home fragment after this line listChannel = response.body().getItems(); , try to print size of listChannel using log or system println type listChannel.size and check what is it

Comment: Hi @Vickyexpert check this image https://s31.postimg.org/f43pw87i3/result.png

Answer (score 0):

Please change your below code in Adapter class,

```
@Override
public ChannelViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                        int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(rowLayout, parent, false);
    return new ChannelViewHolder(view);
}
```

Comment: now one thing you can check is below otherwise your code seems to ok and it should display result

So just check as you are getting proper object or not on onBindViewHolder method

try to do this Log.e("Data", "Name:  " + channels.get(position).getName());

Comment: Hi @Vickyexpert check this : https://s32.postimg.org/mg6yo2p79/result.png

Comment: Any idea @Vickyexpert ?