# RecyclerView not show the data when I run on android 6.0 (Real Device or Emulator)

Tags: java, android

Related on my prev issue : [RecyclerView can not display the data retrieved from the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38058881/recyclerview-can-not-display-the-data-retrieved-from-the-server)

I want to ask if there are differences in using android 6.0 with RecyclerView? Once I found my subject matter is because I use the emulator is intended for API 23. However, when I use the emulator is set using API 19, then my problems disappear and the data is displayed properly in RecyclerView.

For detail my configuration

```
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion 23.0.3
minSdkVersion 19
targetSdkVersion 24
```

I only use the internet permissions in my applications. And to my knowledge the internet permissions have been given full access and no need to do this manually access exemption. Maybe I'm wrong, if yes, please help this problem so that my application could run well on Android 6.0 or higher

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For API 23, check if the permissions are given under APP Permissions in the app settings.Each permission has to be given explicitly in API23 and higher

If the data is being shown in API 19, it ideally should be visible in API 23.

Comment: Hi @yash sachadeva I already add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` in my AndroidManifest.xml. Whether to display the data using RecyclerView in API 23 need special permission?

Comment: In the emulator that you're using, go to settings->apps-your app->app permissions and there enable the permission.
Usually android prompts the user for these permissions

Comment: And what about real device? I test on real device but I dont see any prompts for permissions

Comment: Checked the emulator snapshot, it's not a permission issue, must be something with the code

Comment: Does your code have any if(Build.Version.SDK_INT) statements?

Comment: No I dont have. How should I make? @yash sachdeva

Comment: MainActivity : http://pastebin.com/SxUUumju , 
ChannelAdapter : http://pastebin.com/Jq8Vje5T , 
HomeFragment : http://pastebin.com/ihb337jx , 
Channel : http://pastebin.com/PuRFceZT

Comment: are you sure that this is a android version specific issue?Also check the response that you're getting

Comment: Wait... I will show you the different from emulator result

Comment: Hi @yash sachdeva please see this result : 

1. https://s32.postimg.org/nkxftagsl/android_API_23_emulator.png

2. https://s31.postimg.org/t568taj3v/android_API_19_emulator.png

You can see the different when I use 2 emulator with API23 and API 19